# Using OneNote Interop object launches OneNote Application automatically

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop, onenote

I am observing a weird issue. I am trying to access the OneNote notes in my WPF application using OneNote interop API's. It's working perfectly fine but suddenly now whenever my application launches, it automatically starts OneNote application as well (as I am creating OneNote interop Application instance to access OneNote page).

If it expected? Earlier, I wasn't seeing any such behavior.

Comment: can you share your code for more assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a

`NavigateTo(...);` - Method?

This opens the OneNote-Application.